# ObjC categories not recognised from a different target

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category, swift-extensions

I have an iOS SwiftUI project with the following hierarchy:

```
Module hierarchy:

AppTarget -> depends on Experience
Experience -> depends on Lifecycle
Lifecycle

Content of each module:
Lifecycle 
  -- struct conforming App protocol (entry point)
  -- AppDelegate, SceneDelegate etc.
Experience
  -- URLHandler (and other supporting classes to handle launch parameters (if app is launched by tapping an associated file, quick action etc..) and update the UI.
```

I have a struct conforming to App protocol in the `Lifecycle` library. It defines the [onOpenURL(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:)) method to handle all URL based launches (widgets, files, deep links, universal links etc.).

```
// In Lifecycle library

WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .onOpenURL(perform: { (url: URL) in
            // Handle URL with which the app is launched.
        })
}
```

In the above method, I need to invoke the URL handler method in `Experience` library. Note that the `Experience` library is above `Lifecycle` in the hierarchy (as mentioned above), so I cannot simply directly invoke it.

I'm thinking of using [ObjC categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) to achieve this. ObjC category is a way to add methods to an existing class. At runtime, all methods in the category would be under one single class, though they are defined in two files in different modules.

In `Lifecycle` library, I define the class as below:

```
// In header file,
@interface  URLHandler : NSObject

// No methods defined here.
// Experience extends this using the concept of
// ObjC category and defines a handler method
// to handle all URL handler launches.

@end

// In .mm file, 
@implementation URLHandler

// Empty

@end
```

And in the `Experience` library, I'm extending them as shown below:

```
// In header file, extend the base class in Lifecycle library
// by creating a category.
@interface URLHandler (Experience)

+ (void) handleURL:(NSURL *) url;

@end

// In .mm file,
@implementation URLHandler (Experience)

+ (void) handleURL:(NSURL *) url {
    Log([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(ObjC++) url = %@", [url absoluteString]]);

    // Update the UI after 'understanding' the URL.
}

@end
```

And, in the onOpenURL(perform:) method, invoke handleURL: method,

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .onOpenURL(perform: { (url: URL) in
            URLHandler.handleURL(url)
        })
}
```

As per my understanding, everything seems fine... but I get a compilation error

```
Type 'URLHandler' has no member 'handleURL'
```

Isn't category a runtime feature? At runtime, handleURL: method should be part of `URLHandler`. But how do I get past this error at compile time?

Is this not possible using ObjC? If yes, is there any other way?

**Edit1**: I am using the latest [Cpp-Swift interop](https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/) introduced in WWDC 2023, which uses a module map to expose C++ and ObjC types to Swift. I believe I've done that correctly since the error is not `undefined symbol: URLHandler` but a method not being available in the class, which I implemented in the category.

Comment: Have you added the relevant header to AppTarget-Bridging-Header.h (and configured a bridging header in your project).

Comment: @WarrenBurton I'm using the recent Cpp interoperability, which doesn't require a bridging header, but a module map to expose C++ and ObjC types to Swift. And the new interior is implemented correctly, because I'm able to access the URLHandler in Swift. The error is not `Undefined symbol URLHandler`, but a missing method, which I implemented in the category. Sorry, I missed to add the interop thing in the question.